# Getting wrong output in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I've a course table with the columns,
`id`, `teacher_id` and `name`.

This is the method that I'm using to get a course by id.

```
public static Course getById(int id) throws SQLException {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE id = ?" ;
        Course course = new Course();
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try{
                DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ());
                connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectDb.CONN_STRING, ConnectDb.USERNAME, ConnectDb.PASSWORD);
                statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                statement.setInt(1, id);
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    course.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                    course.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                    course.setTeacherId(resultSet.getInt("teacher_id"));

                }
            }catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e);

            }finally{
                if (resultSet != null) resultSet.close();;
                if (statement != null) statement.close();
                if(connection != null) connection.close();
            }

        return course;



    }// end of method
```

When I run this method, I get an output id :0, teacher_id : 0

The server log says that I've an SQLException

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

Comment: Have you debugged into the code at all? You'll get that return value if there are no results at all... perhaps you should be throwing an exception at that point instead?

Comment: Or just not matching any rows; I'll bet you dollars to doughnuts that `new Course` gives you a course with zeros for those fields. Step 1 is **always** debugging: [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You might not have data for that `id` in the database. And, the result that you are seeing is default values for int types.

Comment: Off-topic: Strongly recommend looking at the [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which would make that close shorter and cleaner.

Comment: The id exists, I've updated the question with the error log.

Comment: @GordThompson's right about the dupe. (I can't vote again, so can't DupeHammer it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is here:

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

You're not calling [`PreparedStatement#executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--), you're calling [`Statement#executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-) (`Statement` is a superinterface of `PreparedStatement`). So the parameter substitution isn't happening and you're actually sending that `?` to the server.

Change it to:

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
// No argument here ---------------^
```

(And yes, this is an API design flaw; and no, you're not the first to fall into it.)

---

There are a few other things about that code that could use improvement:

1. You're always returning a `Course`, even if an exception occurred. Best practices would be to allow the exception to propagate to the caller; second-best practices would be to return some kind of flag to the caller that an error occurred, such as `null`.
2. The try-with-resources statement can make that code both shorter and clearer
3. You shouldn't have to cast the return values of `getConnection` or `prepareStatement`.
4. You're using `while`, but you're expecting only a single result. `if` would make more sense.
5. On that topic, you can give the driver a hint in that regard by using [`setMaxRows`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows-int-).
6. Your method declares that it can throw `SQLException`, which is literally true since it calls `close`, but the only *useful* `SQLException` is actually being caught, logged, and suppressed by the code, making declaring it on the method a bit misleading.
7. I'm told modern JDBC drivers don't need the `registerDriver` call anymore. (I personally haven't used JDBC for a while now, so...)

Here's an example incoporating the above. It allows an exception to propagate, so *errors* (exceptional conditions) are not handled in the normal flow of code; it returns `null` if there's no matching course:

```
public static Course getById(int id) throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE id = ?";

    try (
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectDb.CONN_STRING, ConnectDb.USERNAME, ConnectDb.PASSWORD);
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ) {
        statement.setInt(1, id);
        statement.setMaxRows(1);
        try (
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        ) {
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                Course course = new Course();
                course.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                course.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                course.setTeacherId(resultSet.getInt("teacher_id"));
                return course;
            }

            // No matching course
            return null;
        }
    }

} // end of method
```

That can probably be improved further, but you get the idea.

Comment: Worked like magic. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeus: No worries. I've added a note to the end of the answer as well, could be useful. Note that try-with-resources requires JDK 7 or higher.

Comment: I just can't get try with resources to work on Eclipse, this code looks so much better.